# Error: object reference not set to an instance of an object en unity

Tags: c#, unity, unity3d

Yo estaba viendo un tutorial de como agregarle una pistola a un juego de unity, hice (según yo) todos los pasos bien pero cuando agrego el script al jugador y intento poner el modelo de la pistola no me deja, aquí esta el código y una imagen de lo que me pasa:
[image: )]

En el lado izquierdo de la imagen esta el modelo y a la derecha esta el script, lo que no funciona es el element 0 (no me deja arrastrar el model al element 0)

Aquí el código:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerWeaponController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<WeaponController> startingWeapons = new List<WeaponController>();

    public Transform weaponParentSocket;
    public Transform defaultWeaponPosition;
    public Transform aimingPosition;

    public int activeWeaponIndex { get; private set; }
    
    private WeaponController[] weaponSlots = new WeaponController[5];
    

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        activeWeaponIndex = -1;

        foreach (WeaponController startingWeapon in startingWeapons)
        {
            AddWeapon(startingWeapon);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1))
        {
            SwitchWeapon(0);
        }




    }

    private void SwitchWeapon(int p_weaponIndex)
    {
        if (p_weaponIndex != activeWeaponIndex && p_weaponIndex >= 0)
        {
            weaponSlots[p_weaponIndex].gameObject.SetActive(true);
            activeWeaponIndex = p_weaponIndex;
        }


    }

    private void AddWeapon(WeaponController p_weaponPrefab)
    {
        weaponParentSocket.position = defaultWeaponPosition.position;

        for (int i = 0; i<weaponSlots.Length; i++)
        {
            if (weaponSlots[i] == null)
            {
                WeaponController weaponClone = Instantiate(p_weaponPrefab, weaponParentSocket);
                weaponClone.gameObject.SetActive(false);


                weaponSlots[i] = weaponClone;
                return;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que esta ocurriendo es que le estas pasando como argumento un objeto prefabricado `(GameObject)` mientras que en el inspector estaría requiriendo un tipo `WeaponController` al cual no puede acceder si el objeto no se encuentra en la escena, si agregas el objeto prefabricado a la escena y este posee un `MonoBehaviour` de tipo `WeaponController` deberá acceder al mismo de manera correcta, sin embargo si pretendes un instanciamiento de estos deberás cambiar el tipo de tu lista de

> `List<WeaponController> startingWeapons` -> `List<GameObject> startingWeapons`

Y luego acceder a sus propiedades desde el script. Saludos, suerte en tu aprendizaje.